# Get packet loss from Open Flow switch

Tags: openflow, mininet, packet-loss, openvswitch, sdn

I am using ryu controller (3.22) to monitor switches (Open vSwitch 2.0.2, supporting Open Flow 1.3), which are a part of virtual network created using mininet (2.1.0). It is a tree topology with depth = 2, and fanout = 5. I am using [switch_monitor.py](https://github.com/osrg/ryu-book/blob/master/en/source/sources/simple_monitor.py)

With the help of controller, I can get port statistics using the `EventOFPPortStatsReply` decorator. I can get values of `rx_packets`, `rx_bytes`, `rx_errors`, `tx_packets`, `tx_bytes`, `tx_errors`, `rx_dropped`, `tx_dropped` etc.

But the values of `rx_dropped`, `tx_dropped` come out to be **zero** always, even when the switches are actually dropping packets, as reported by qdisc (linux command).

**How to get packet loss statistics from an Open Flow switch?**

**a. How to get a non zero value?**

**b. Is there any alternate way?**

Comment: Have you solved the problem?! I have the same problem. I use “ tc qdisc .." to simulate errors on ports but Ryu port stats return no error and no packet loss, I am using OVS too..

Comment: It's long time ago. I don't remember now @Paulo

Answer (score 0):

qdisc reports what the kernel is dropping, not what the network is dropping. You're getting zero's because the switch isn't dropping frames.

(I don't know if your virtual network system supports simulating frame drops.)

Comment: This can be the issue, i'll check

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `dropped` only cares about packets that are dropped due to actual `drop` rules or due to buffer overflows.

Another way to calculate packet loss is to compare the packet counts for the two switches on the edge of a link. Suppose you have `A <--> B` and want to calculate the packet loss rate from A to B. Then you take:

```
plr(A,B) = (tx_packets(A) - rx_packets(B)) / tx_packets(A))
```

Beware though that sometimes the counters are reset leading to `rx_packets` being higher that `tx_packets`. I am facing this behavior in my SDN software and tend to invalidate the results, if there are strange combinations.